# How to write where Between query in Yii2 with integer as a second parameter

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I have this query in PostgreSQL that I want to implement in my model in Yii2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE 1492257600 BETWEEN start AND end
```

`start` and `end` are attributes of `some_table`.
In my model, I tried the following but, no matter how I write it, it keeps throwing the same error.

```
$results = static::find()->where(['between', 1492257600, 'start', 'end'])
                ->all();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> ```
> Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column \"1492257600\" does not exist
> The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM \"some_table\" WHERE \"1492257600\" BETWEEN 'start' AND 'end'"
> ```

When the query is built, these symbols `" "` are added to the integer, so PostgreSQL thinks it is a column of the table.

Can anyone tell me how to write the where between correctly?

Comment: From the documentation: between: operand 1 should be the column name, and operand 2 and 3 should be the starting and ending values of the range that the column is in

Comment: @Patrick So, what are you telling me is that I can not use between to build that specific query, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is dedicated [`BetweenColumnsCondition`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-conditions-betweencolumnscondition) expression for such cases:

```
use yii\db\conditions\BetweenColumnsCondition;

$results = static::find()
    ->where(new BetweenColumnsCondition(1492257600, 'BETWEEN', 'start', 'end'))
    ->all();
```

It automatically quotes column names and escapes value, so it should be more convenient than simple `yii\db\Expression`.

---

Also note that `WHERE 1492257600 BETWEEN start AND end` may be slower than `WHERE 1492257600 >= start AND 1492257600 <= end`, I suggest to do some performance test if your table may grow big and usage indexes is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with postgresql but this will work same as between,

```
$results = self::find()
   ->where(['>=', 'start', 1492257600])
   ->andWhere(['<=', 'end', 1492257600])
   ->all();
```

Comment: Yes, that will work but with value as second item. Thanks... 
It seems to me that using 'between' is impossible for this specific case. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: [Yii2 Doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression)

When an Expression object is embedded within a SQL statement or fragment, it will be replaced with the `$expression` property value without any DB escaping or quoting.

so You'll have something like this:

```
$expression = new \yii\db\Expression('1492257600 BETWEEN start AND end');
$results = self::find()->where($expression)
            ->all();
```