# Yii2 andFilterWhere BETWEEN first value then column

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I need to create query using yii2. Query should looks like:

```
WHERE '2022-09-19' BETWEEN po.start_date AND po.end_date
OR '2022-09-25' BETWEEN po.start_date AND po.end_date
```

Im trying to create that using:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['OR', ['BETWEEN', '2022-09-19', 'po.start_date ', 'po.end_date'], ['BETWEEN', '2022-09-25', 'po.start_date ', 'po.end_date']]);
```

But this generated SQL

```
WHERE (`2022-09-19` BETWEEN 'po.start_date' AND 'po.end_date') OR (`2022-09-25` BETWEEN 'po.start_date ' AND 'po.end_date')
```

is incorrect and throws `Unknown column '2022-09-19' in 'where clause'`. Does anyone know how I can generate that SQL? I need to remove ` from first argument and ' from column names to make it working.

Comment: Exactly but I have no idea how to make that in yii2 query builder, when Im trying to do that like in docs it generates me incorrect SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write where Between query in Yii2 with integer as a second parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624411/how-to-write-where-between-query-in-yii2-with-integer-as-a-second-parameter)